# Asking if you are there いますか or いるの？

Tags: meaning, words

I want to ask if someone is there. Can both terms be used to ask if a person is there/are you there? いますか or いるの？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume what you are asking is "どなたか／誰か + いますか？／いるの？" construction.

> どなたか／誰か + **いますか**？

means you want to **get the reply** from someone if they are staying there.

So, if someone is replying, it might **relieve** you.

> どなたか／誰か + **いるの**？

means you **are wondering** if someone is there since it is **unlikely/no sign** someone is staying there. So, if someone is replying, it might **surprise** you.

Comment: the correct spelling is relieve.

Comment: This is understandable now, I appreciate it.